# allow subscribers to see private posts without plug in

Tags: php, functions

I do not want another plug in but rather want to create custom code that will allow a logged in subscriber to view private posts. I want them to be able to view all private posts, not only their own.

I have found this below online but dont know what white spider is and dont trust it. What would I edit or modify here to make this my own?

```
function none(){
 $subRole = get_role( 'subscriber' );
 $subRole->add_cap( 'read_private_posts' );
$subRole->add_cap( 'read_private_pages' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'ws_private_posts_subscribers' );
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be added as a basic hook -

```
function what-ever-youwantto-callthis() {

$subRole = get_role( 'subscriber' ); //change the name of the user here 

$subRole->add_cap( 'read_private_posts' ); //allows the above to read posts 

$subRole->add_cap( 'read_private_pages' ); //allows the above to read pages

}

add_action( 'init', 'what-ever-youwantto-callthis' );
```